# How do I change width of Rails collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set the width of an options select box in a Rails view. The html_options tag doesn't seem to be working for me, or I have something wrong with the syntax? I keep on ending up with the default width. How do I change the width?

View:

```
  <div class="field">
    <label for="person">Permit</label><br/>
    <%= collection_select("cityzone_citypermit", "citypermit_id" , @permit_infos, "id", "permit_info", html_options = {:style => "width:300px"}) %> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
collection_select("cityzone_citypermit", "citypermit_id" , @permit_infos, "id", "permit_info",{},  {:style => "width:300px"})
```

The last two options accept hashes. So go for one empty hash and one with your html_options

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with collection_select, but from what I can see from the docs, you're meant to just pass in just a hash (without the html_options bit.)

I think it should actually be somewhere along the lines of this:

```
<%= collection_select("cityzone_citypermit", "citypermit_id" , @permit_infos, "id", "permit_info", {style: "width:300px"}) %>
```

Give that a try and let me know how that goes.